# Make directory named 0001 instead of 1 in a bash script loop

Tags: bash

In the following bash script if j=0000 how have I to change the following bash script to make dirs named 0001, 0002, ...? Actually it make dirs named 1, 2, 3

```
for i in *.jpg; do let j+=1 ; mkdir $j ; done
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Your current script uses only a decimal value - this obviously translates to the value without leading zeroes.

You would have to pad the string to the length of 4 characters, with leading zeroes. You do this by using backticks ``` `` ``` to get the result of the printf call `printf  %04d $j`.

As a result, you should have the full command:

```
for i in *.jpg; do let j+=1; mkdir `printf %04d $j`; done
```

**Source:** [StackOverflow: bash - Padding zeros in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117134/padding-zeros-in-a-string)

(Obviously also see the further answers to that question, if you want a more in-depth solution, but this definitely works perfectly for this use case.)

Answer (score 5):

Using bash, your best option is:

```
mkdir {0001..0666}
```

to create dirs with name `0001` to `0666` (with zero padding).

If you want directories named `prefix0001suffix`, `prefix0002suffix`, ... then:

```
mkdir prefix{0001..0666}suffix
```

will do.

If you only want odd number directory names

```
mkdir {0001..0666..2}
```

and so on... See [*Brace Expansion* in the `bash` reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

As FEichinger points out, you need to know in advance the number of directories. If you want a solution that is close to yours, but really safe and using more modern bash idiom:

```
for i in *.jpg; do ((++j)); mkdir $(printf "%04d" $j) ; done
```

Comment: This is only useful for a previously known amount of directories to be created. Usually, when using numbered directories, you are within a dynamic context - which means it should determine the amount at runtime and thus still needs string padding. Depends on the specific use case, though.

Comment: @FEichinger Right! post edited accordingly.